# Need to watch for files in a particular directory and move them to a folder

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I have a dropzone where users drop the file. Once the files are dropped they need to be moved to a directory based on who created/dropped the files. Main problem is the script has to wait till user drops 2 files of different formats

Example: file1.abc (These files can in multiple)
file2.xyz. file2.xyz will be a single file. Once these 2 files are dropped in the dropzone, script has to create a directory based on username and move those files into that directory.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I tried filtering based on owner but was not sure how to wait till both files are dropped.

```
Hi tripleee, i wrote the below script                                                     #! /bin/bash

own1=`find . -name "*.html" -printf "%u\n" | sort -u`
ownCount=`find . -name "*.html" -printf "%u\n" | sort -u | wc -l`
File1=`find . -name "*.py" -printf "%u\n" | sort -u`
File1Count=`find . -name "*.py" -printf "%u\n" | sort -u | wc -l`
fileCount=`$((ownCount + File1Count))`

if [ \( "$fileCount" -gte 2 -a "$own1" = "$File1" \ ]; then
        mkdir ./$own1
        for type in $own1
        do
                find . -type f -user $own1 -print 2>/dev/null -exec cp -n {} ./$own1 \;
        done

else
        sleep 10
fi
```

when i run the above command, get the below error message. not sure why   ./a.sh: line 6: 2+1: command not found
./a.sh: line 8: /1: Permission denied
./a.sh: line 9: [: missing `]'

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957484/linux-watch-a-directory-for-new-files-then-run-a-script

Comment: Thank you tripleee. But my command has to wait till i get 2 files saspecified in my problem statement. Once those 2 files are received, it has to create the directories

Comment: So what have you tried? Running a script which checks whether it has two files to process should not be too hard. But we expect you to show your attempts or at least a good explanation of where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Hi Tripleee, This is what i tried                                                                                                          file1=`ls -l | grep "*.xyz"| awk '{print $3}'`
inFile=`ls -l | grep "*.abc"| awk '{print $3}'`
if [ $inFile == $file1]
then 
 mkdir inFile
 chmod 777 inFile
 <<<How to copy only those 2 files>>> 
else
 wait()
fi

Comment: I am not getting how to copy only those 2 files OR files any number of files particular to that user

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You want to revert to sane permissions (probably 755 for your use case?) and plan to learn to understand the Unix permission model soon. Allowing any user on the system write access to your stuff is a recipe for privilege escalation - if your box is pwned, the hacker will look for exactly this kind of mistake to get to the next level.

Comment: If you are on Linux or otherwise have access to GNU `find`, you can easily find the owner as well as time stamp etc of found files. "How can I extract the owner of a file" and "how can I copy *n* files which match a particular pattern" are both popular questions which have many answers on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to show what you have searched for already and how the things you found didn't work.

Comment: Also, `grep 'x' | awk '{ y }'` is a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) which can easily be refactored to `awk '/x/ { y }'`

Comment: `# How to copy only those 2 files?` `cp "$file1" "$file2" destination`. Also in `[ $inFile == $file1]` you need a space before `]` and the variables should be quoted. Also `wait()` is kind of strange, I think you want to just `inotifywait -e create`.

Comment: Thanks Guys, Let me check on the input provided,

Comment: Hi triplee, i updated the code. I am running into some issues can you please help?

Comment: i got the code fixed. but the problem is own1=`find . -name "*.html" -printf "%u\n" | sort -u` returns multiple user name and becuase of that if condition is invalidated. Not sure how to match owner and copy the files