# bash: keep running script with parallel command indefinitely

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-parallel

I have logging system that creates new log file every second in Ubuntu Server. I have developed script called "processor.sh" that runs every second to extract important information from the newly created log files. Previously, I used to use watch command to run the processors.sh indefinitely:

```
watch -n1 ./processor.sh
```

Now I started to use parallel command like the following:

```
ls *.log | parallel xargs ./processors.sh
```

I believe using watch to run it continuously is a wrong thing. How can I keep running processor.sh forever every second with parallel command?

Comment: Your design of creating a new log file every second sounds flawed. Maybe you need to redesign the application that is generating the data. Maybe you should generate your data directly into a database or somesuch.

Comment: `How can I keep running processor.sh forever every second with parallel command?` - that makes no sense, at least with parallel. Please explain it better. For example there are 100 files in the folder. How many processor.sh processes do you want to run? After 1 second, how many processer.sh processes do you want to run? How are the processor.sh script related to the files? Why do you want to use parallel? How is xargs related to it? And, what is the point of creating a application that creates a new log file each second? Why?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808856/3727050 - Monitor directory for new files and invoke your script with each new file. No parallel processing I think tho

Comment: modify `processor.sh` as such: create a function to process a given file, then have script run an infinite loop with a 1 second sleep interval - `while true; do find-file-and-call-function &; sleep 1; done`; then kick off `processor.sh` in a screen session; you could go a bit further and create a crontab entry to call `processor.sh` every XX minutes and then add logic to the script to check for another instance already running (if already running then quietly exit this run, otherwise continue on with rest of logic); though I agree with the the other comments re: your design ... **WHY** ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
while true; do
  parallel ./processors.sh ::: *.log
  sleep 1
done
```

But I think this will be way better:

```
inotifywait -qmre MOVED_TO -e CLOSE_WRITE --format %w%f `pwd` |
  parallel ./processors.sh
```

This will start the processing when another process stops writing to a .log-file and closes it.